# How to refresh all values after submiting in jquery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, partial-page-refresh

I would like to refresh all values to default in page which consist of input,select after submit in jquery mobile.How can I do that,kindly help me on that.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery not jQuery mobile.

So, the HTML:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there two">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The JS:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#target :input").each(function(){
      $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
  });
});
```